# lvalue required as left operand of assignment in c for an if statement in c language

Tags: c

i was writing a c code for my college assignment and this error keeps popping up which i don't understand why.
The error is "lvalue required as left operand of assignment in c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* readFile;
    FILE* resultFile;

    int charCount, wordCount, spaceCount;
    char readFileName[100];
    char ch;

    printf("enter file name here:");
    scanf("%s", readFileName);
    readFile = fopen(readFileName, "r");

    if(readFile = NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file %s make sure the name and path of the is correct");

    }
    else
    {
        while((ch = fgetc(readFile)) != EOF)
        {
            charCount++;

            if(ch = ' ' || ch = '\n' || ch = '\t' || ch = '\0')  /* error is shown on this line*/
            {
                wordCount++;
            }
            if(ch = ' ')
            {
                spaceCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(readFile);

    resultFile = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    fprintf("numbers of characters:%d\nnumbers of words:%d\nnumbers of spaces:%d\n", charCount, wordCount, spaceCount);
    fclose(resultFile);

    printf("your result result has been delivered into ""result.txt"" file");
    return 0;
}
```

I never faced this error before and i'm completely clueless.
and the program fails to compile

Comment: it should be `if(readFile == NULL)` with `==`, not `=`. `=` is to assign a new value to the variable on the left side. `==` is to compare for equality

Comment: Also note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`** value, which is rather important for that comparison against the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: And you messed up the assignment versus comparison for equality elsewhere as well. Which is why you get an error.

Comment: Anyone knows of a canonical duplicate for this? We ought to have one.

Comment: Even after your edit, there are a lot of assingments where you wanted comparisons.

Comment: thanks @Someprogrammerdude, i've got it to compile.

Comment: It compiles, ship it! No, there are other bugs as well.

Comment: Also please don't edit your post to "fix bugs". The reason you are asking is because there are bugs. If you remove them, the question no longer makes sense to future readers and posted answers might turn obsolete.

Comment: Also, character classification is not that simple as it seems you might think. Perhaps start reading [from here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to read the error:

- Left operand of assignment is clear enough: `something = ...`. Where `=` is the assignment operator.
- "lvalue" basically means a value which has a place in memory and may get modified. Plain read/write access of variables is called "lvalue access". The term originates from "left value", as in left of `=`

So now we have to go check your code for fishy assignments:

- `readFile = NULL`, `ch = ' '` and so on. `ch` is actually a "lvalue" so that part is valid C. Any decent compiler should however warn you against these.  "Assignment inside condition", "Possible incorrect assignment" etc. It's the silly old `=` instead of `==` bug.

  `=` has lower operator precedence than `||`, which in turn has lower operator precedence than `==`.   Because of that, the compiler stumbles over something like `'\t' || ch = '\0'` which it reads as `('\t' || ch) = '\0'`. Where `('\t' || ch)` is not a "lvalue". Hence the error.

Comment: the program does compile but it fails to run successfully and i don't understand why because it doesn't show any error anymore.

Comment: if you can identify more bugs please help me bro.

Comment: @NickGz The "lvalue required as left operand of assignment in c" would typically block the program from running. Anyway, since you are a beginner you should compile with `gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` to get maximum warnings and turn all of them into errors.

Comment: @NickGz Then it's time to start a new question that shows the updated code, and describes what you mean by "fails to run successfully". What did the program do that you didn't expect it to do, or what did it not do that it should have done.

Comment: Yeah indeed, please post a separate question with the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

While the real fix for your problem is to use `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment), it's worth to notice the reason for the error message.

In principle there is nothing wrong by doing an assignment in the `if` condition. Doing:

```
if(ch = ' ') {...};
```

is perfectly legal.

The reason you get that error message is operator precedence, i.e. `||` has higher precedence than `=`.

So

```
if(ch = ' ' || ch = '\n') {...};
```

will be evaluated like:

```
if(ch = (' ' || ch) = '\n') {...};
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
        Evaluated first

        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Evaluated secondly (as boolean-result = '\n')
```

and the result of the first expression is 0 or 1 which isn't an lvalue. So the code tries to assign `'\n'` to the result of a boolean expression.

Comment: The order of evaluation of the operands of = is unspecified. And that's not the problem, the problem lies in the evaluation of the left operand, no matter the order. C has a constraint that "an assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand".

Comment: @Lundin There are only one operand to be evaluated here.

Comment: The = operator has two operands. It is unspecified if `(' ' || ch)` or `'\n'` is evaluated first. The compiler detects the error at the point when the left operand has been evaluated and it is not an lvalue.

Comment: @Lundin There is nothing yo evaluate in `'\n'`. Further it doesn't matter at all for this question

Comment: (The order of) evaluation is a formal C term. Upon reading your answer one might incorrectly believe that some left-to-right order is guaranteed. In fact it _does_ matter for this question because the full expression is `ch = ' ' || ch = '\n' || ch = '\t' || ch = '\0'`. Now in which order is this evaluated... because of precedence the expression is equivalent to `ch = (' ' || ch) = ('\n' || ch) = ('\t' || ch) = '\0'`. Where the compiler starts to evaluate that mess will determine what compiler error you get. The `ch = (' ' || ch)` sub-expression is for example valid and well-defined C.

Comment: @Lundin `ch = (' ' || ch)` will not be done first. The assignment to `ch` is the last to happen be it wont because `('\t' || ch) = '\0'` is illegal.

Comment: @Lundin I don't understand why you think it indicate any kind of "left-to-right order guarantee." Since `||` has higher precedence `(' ' || ch)` will be done first. Then the result of that sub-expression will be assigned the value `'\n'` due to right-to-left of assingments. But the assigments is illegal so gives a compiler error. Adding more terms doesn't change the fundamentals.

Comment: Order of evaluation and operator precedence are different things. The compiler may evaluate any sub-expression in any order it likes. But precedence/associativity means it must parse the expression so that it gets the equivalent result of `ch = ((' ' || ch) = (('\n' || ch) = (('\t' || ch) = '\0')))`. Yeah there's a mistake in my previous comment, `ch = (' ' || ch)` doesnt form a sub-expression. But the compiler could for example decide to grab the `('\n' || ch) ` from right in the middle first, evaluate it, then realize it's the left operand of an assignment and then flag constraint violation.

Comment: @Lundin I never ever claimed evaluation and operator precedence is the same. I have no idea why you keep going on about that. The compiler error will be the same in all cases and it comes due to operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

When you`re doing a comparation you have to use two equals simbol like

```
if (ch == ' '){
    then do something...
}
```

you can use

```
ch = ' ';
```

to produce a empty char that contains ' '
but in your conditional that will show you an error!